# Stellar Test Network - periodically purged?

Tags: testnet

Today, I noticed some of my test accounts were no longer on the test network (I recreated them via the friendbot).  Is there a periodic purging of the test network?  Or is there something going on right now with the test network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [the testnet is periodically reset](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/test-net.html#periodic-reset-of-testnet-data).